# sqlalchemy PRI and MUL keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating sqlalchemy python script to create tables in sql database.

I need to build a table with keys as PRI and MUL both.

And here is what I have written to achieve that.

```
test_table = Table('test', metadata, Column('ClientID', Integer, unique=False,
                                            autoincrement=False,
                                            primary_key=True, nullable=False,
                                            server_default=text('0')),
                   Column('UserID', Integer, unique=False, autoincrement=False,
                          primary_key=True, nullable=False),
                   Column('ContactID', Integer, unique=False,
                          autoincrement=False, primary_key=True,
                          nullable=False),
                   Column('ConvoID', Integer, unique=False,
                          autoincrement=False, primary_key=True,
                          nullable=False),
                   Column('Direction', String(4), unique=False,
                          autoincrement=False, primary_key=True,
                          nullable=False), Column('Variable', sa.Unicode(100,
                                                                         collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
                                                  primary_key=True,
                                                  nullable=False),
                   Column('Value',
                          sa.Unicode(255, collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
                          nullable=True),
                   Column('CreatedDate', DateTime,
                          server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
                          nullable=False),
                   Column('UpdatedDate', DateTime,
                          server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
                          nullable=False),
                   Index('UserID', 'UserID', 'ContactID', 'ConvoID'),
                   )
```

But the problem is , I am not able to set this 3 columns  (`UserID`, `ContactID` and `ConvoId`) as MUL keys.

Can anyone please help me with this ?